# for loop generator with a sentinel

Tags: python, generator

I have an application with one producer and many consumers, and a queue, which communicates them. 
The consumer should collect some data from queue, let's say `qsize()/number_of_consumers`, but it must stop it work when a `sentinel` appears.

I have such a code:

```
frame = 0
elems_max = 10
while frame is not None:
    frames = []
    for _ in range(elems_max):
        frame = queue_in.get()
        if frame:
            frames.append(frame)
        else:
            break
   process_data(frames)
```

As You can see `None` is a sentinel for this queue, and when it appears I wan't to break my working process. I also want to get more then one element for data processing.

What is the fastest method to achieve this [in python 3.5]?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to break my working process"? Do you mean your `while` loop?

Comment: Yes, i wan't to break my for and while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to break your outer `while` when encountering a `None`.

You can hold a boolean variable that is `True` while the `while` must execute, and `False` when it should stop.

This would look like this:

```
frame = 0
elems_max = 10
running = True
while running and frame is not None:
    frames = []
    for _ in range(elems_max):
        frame = queue_in.get()
        if frame is not None:
            frames.append(frame)
        else:
            running = False
            break
   process_data(frames)
```

The `break` instruction will break the inner `for`, but not the outer `while`.
However, having set `running` to `False`, the `while` loop will stop.

---

Based on your comment.

It is not possible to include a `break` statement in a comprehension, nor an `else` clause, as you wanted to do:

frames = [f for i in range(elems_max) if queue_in.get() is not None else break]

However, you can build your list, and then remove all the elements after a `None`:

```
frames = [queue_in.get() for _ in range(elems_max)]

try:
    noneId = frames.find(None)
    frames = frames[:noneId]
except ValueError:
    pass
```

This is not very efficient, because potentially many elements will be appended in `frames` for nothing.
I would prefer a manual construction, to avoid this hazard.

---

One more solution, based on a generator.
This might not be what you expected, but the syntax is rather simple, so you may like it.

The idea is to wrap the getting of the data inside of a generator, that breaks on a `None` value:

```
def queue_data_generator(queue, count):
    for _ in range(count):
        item = queue.get()
        if item is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            yield item
```

Then, instantiate this generator, and simply iterate over it:

```
g = queue_data_generator(queue_in, elems_max)
frames = [frame for frame in g]
```

The `frames` list will contain all the frames contained in `queue_in`, until the first `None`.
The usage is rather simple, but you have to setup it by defining the generator.
I think it's pretty elegant though.

Comment: It's not the purpose of my question, with my code the while loop breaks. I wan't a the fastest method for this code, if there's one?

Comment: @GrzegorzGłowacki Well, I don't know what Python you're using, but `break` definitely won't break the `while`: as stated [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops), "The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop.". Anyway, what do you mean by "the fastest method"? If you want the shortest code, then putting your `while` inside of a `try` block is probably the shortest, although it requires you to change your `process_data` function so that it raises an exception.

Comment: break won't break while loop, but frame is set to None, and it'll stop the loop execution

Comment: @GrzegorzGłowacki Indeed, my bad. Anyway, the `try`-`except` solution IMO is absolutely inelegant. You should stick with a boolean flag, that will give you more flexibility. For instance, it could let you stop the process from some other place of your code.

Comment: I'm rather looking for a solution like generator:
{frames = [f for i in range(elems_max) if queue_in.get() is not None else break ]}
if You know what i mean...

Comment: @GrzegorzGłowacki You want to compile this in a list comprehension?

Comment: The data container doesn't matter, but AFAIK the python lists are fastest, so YES.

Comment: @GrzegorzGłowacki Tuples and generators are generally better than lists. Anyway, I edited my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148269/discussion-between-grzegorz-glowacki-and-right-leg).

Comment: The last solution with generator is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I  would do next (kinda pseudocode):

```
class CInputQueue:
    def get(self, preferred_N):
        # do sync stuff
        # take <= N elements (you can do kinda balance the load)
        # or throw exception
        raise Exception("No data, no work, no life.")
             
elems_max = 10
try:
    while True:
       process_data(queue_in.get(elems_max))
except:
    None # break
```

I assume that data processing takes much more time, than 0 ms, so I use exception. I know that it's not okay use exceptions for flow control, but for `worker` it's really exception. His "life" build around processing data, but their is no work for him, no even *sleep task*.